# Find user by custom property identity asp.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to find an user that has a custom property "Token" that I added with database migration, I tried to use:

```cs
var adb = new AppDbContext();
var found = adb.Users.Where(u => u.Token == "ABDJ_SJ_ETC");//Error
//OR found = adb.Users.SingleOrDefault(); Error too
```

My AppDbContext class

AppDbContext.cs

```
namespace MyApp{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>{
         public AppDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection"){}
    }
}
```

AppUser.cs

```
namespace MyApp{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser{
        public string Token {get;set;}
    }
}
```

The error is "System.Data.Entity.IDbSet does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Without the Where line my app runs correctly, add Users to db with my Token, etc.
What i need to do to find an AppUser by that custom field??

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I followed this tutorial without problems: [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks, Visual Studio didn't show me what using directive I needed to use, I added it and that solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Visual Studio didn't suggest me any dependencies to resolve, and i didn't know which directive needed to use,

I added

```
using System.Linq;
```

and that solved the problem

Thanks @p.s.w.g for helping me

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, you can rollover the error line and it will suggest the appropriate missing `using`.

Remember to included in your code the `.SingleOrDefault()` statement in line:

```
var found = adb.Users.Where(u => u.Token == "ABDJ_SJ_ETC").SingleOrDefault()
```

Comment: Update:It's posible to use alt+enter and Visual Studio will suggest to add the using or include inline the respective namespace in the first and second options respectively.

Answer (score 0):

use bottom code for get custom **ApplicationUser** in identity with custom property

```
var context=new AuthContext();
var result=context.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>.SingleOrDefault(item => item.NationalCode == "");
```

**NationalCode** is custom property in **ApplicationUser** 
**ApplicationUser** is custom user that implement IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser :  IdentityUser
{
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
}
```